# passing msiexec command line params to a child process started by msiexec

Tags: installation, wix, command-line-arguments

I  have a requirement to update config files with the command line provided arguments for some reason, the file is not being updated so I wrote a small utility app in c# to be started by msiexec. The intention is to get the commandline params to this app so that it would open the config file and update it during the course of installation.

My app was executed fine but when trying to read the parent process (msiexec) command line params, I get something like `C:\windows\msiexec /V` not the ones I specify on the msiexec command line (I'm not even using `/V`)

Any ideas about what could be the issue? If you have a better way to handle this please suggest.

Thanks.

**Update:**
Sorry for the confusion, I was using WiX installer and I start the WiX generated .msi on the command line as below for eg.

```
C:\> msiexec /I foo.msi ARG1="v1" ARG2="v2"
```

`ARG1` and `ARG2` are defined in Wix installer script.

What I'm looking at is a way to access the command line params `ARG1="v1"`,  `ARG2="V"` by a small application which will be started by msiexec (the app is specified in Wix installer script as custom action).

Ideally, when I use `xmlFile` (tried `xmlConfig` as well), my WiX installer script should be able to update my config files with `v1`, `v2` but its not happening so wrote an application that should be able to read `v1` & `v2` and write to the config file.

using `xmlFile` I get the following error:

> ExecXmlFile: Error 0x8007006e: failed to load XML file: Error 25531. Failed to open XML file , system error: -2147024786 MSI (s) (E4!54) [18:11:36:714]: Product: -- Error 25531. Failed to open XML file , system error: -2147024786 –

Doesn't get any meaningful info. I used the msiexec argument `/l*v` to generate the logging.

---

Log excerpt:

Actually `xmlFile` should do my requirement but I get the following error while using it. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
MSI (s) (E4:00) [18:11:32:110]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=ExecXmlFile,,) Action 18:11:32: ExecXmlFile.
MSI (s) (E4:00) [18:11:32:111]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=ExecXmlFile,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=ExecXmlFile,CustomActionData=1030//cloudRecognition/connectiontype130//cloudRecognition/connectionaddress192.168.128.59;192.168.128.261030//cloudRecognition/connectionport50001;50001)
MSI (s) (E4:DC) [18:11:32:113]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIA419.tmp, Entrypoint: ExecXmlFile
MSI (s) (E4:EC) [18:11:32:113]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (E4:EC) [18:11:32:115]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 10104 (0x2778).
MSI (s) (E4:68) [18:11:32:402]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (E4:68) [18:11:32:403]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom action server.
ExecXmlFile:  Error 0x8007006e: failed to load XML file:
Error 25531. Failed to open XML file , system error: -2147024786
MSI (s) (E4!54) [18:11:36:714]: Product:  -- Error 25531. Failed to open XML file , system error: -2147024786
```

CustomAction `ExecXmlFile` returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the arguments as MSI properties? If yes, then you can read them from the MSI database. Check this:

http://www.alteridem.net/2008/05/20/read-properties-from-an-msi-file/

I am guessing you are setting environment specific application properties to the Config file? If so, why don't you have all the properties defined in the config file and make the application smart enough to read the right properties (by checking the environment)? I would do that.

Above comments are just based on the limited information you provided. You would have your own reasons to do so :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was using WiX installer and I start the WiX generated .msi on the command line as below for eg.

Comment: Please refer to the update on the original question for more details and let me know if you need more details. Thanks for the help

Comment: sorry I should have posted it here but no of characters allowed forced me to post it as answer to my own question. Please have a look and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need to add a CustomAction to your install process.
You might need both or just one, depending of the request that you have.

1. To Update Configuration files  can you use [XmlFile CustomAction](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlfile.htm), to change modify any XML file.
2. To launch a [Quiet Execution](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) CustomAction

I believe that this will allow you to change the values of the configuration file during the installation.  You can find a nice introduction to CustomActions and their types [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm).  Have a look at the type 2 CustomAction.

Edit for follow question in Answer section:

When is the CA scheduled to launch during the installation process?
Do you have a log file for the install?

Re-edit

Without Code or more information about the installation process, I can't really help more.

Helpfull info would be:

1. Where in the installation sequence is your CA launched?
2. What WiX Element are you using to change the values in your file.
3. Did you try to create an installer that does just the part that you are having trouble with, to isolate the behavior.

Comment: CA scheduled to launch after the installation.

Comment: yes, the one I copied is from the log file. i.e. custom action server. ExecXmlFile: Error 0x8007006e: failed to load XML file: Error 25531. Failed to open XML file , system error: -2147024786 MSI (s) (E4!54) [18:11:36:714]: Product: -- Error 25531. Failed to open XML file , system error: -2147024786

Comment: Are you sure the file has been copied?

Comment: Do you have the Authorization to perform the operation

Comment: you mean the xml file that I'm trying to update? if so, the file is already available and the upgrade won't touch the file as I used NeverOverwrite="yes". All my experiment is during the upgrade process which is installed via command line.